# Why does my JavaScript not execute in order?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why my code isn't running in order... The code below doesn't execute the document.write part, but it executes the part after it just fine. I think it has something to do with the timing, giving the browser to execute the . I tried using setTimeout in some parts, but it's either not working, or I'm doing it wrong.

```
function isBrowserMobile()
{
    var iPadAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
    var iPodAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null;
    var AndroidAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) != null;
    var webOSAgent = navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) != null;
    if (iPadAgent || iPodAgent || AndroidAgent || webOSAgent)
    {
       document.write("<body bgcolor='Orange'><b>Mobile browser detected!</b></body>");
       var choice = confirm("Do you want to visit the mobile site?")
       if (choice)
           mobile();
       else
           desktop();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is so much bad in this function. Anyway, can you link to a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem, please?

Comment: *"it executes the part after it just fine"*: and which part is that exactly? If `iPadAgent || iPodAgent || AndroidAgent || webOSAgent` is `false`, then `document.write` is not executed.

Comment: Your desktop version is rendered via `desktop()`? Or is it a NOOP?

Comment: Both mobile() and desktop() calls other functions not listed here. What I mean is that document.write just doesn't execute at all, it just continues to the if...else... part. By the way, I was testing this on my iPod touch, so it should have executed the document.write part.

Comment: I would try replacing the `body` tag with `div`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

I suggest you not to use `document.write` but to use DOM, like the following:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor='Orange';
document.body.innerHTML='This is a text';
```

And when testing your code in a desktop browser you can add `true ||` to the start of the if condition.

*My original answer used innerText which is not a standard*

Answer (score 0):

Browsers rarely update the page before a function has finished processing. So the `document.write` has been executed, but the result may not be displayed until the function is complete.

As minitech said, it's a pretty rubbish function anyway. You should be asking based on screen size, not UA sniffing.

Note that if the function is run after the document has finished loading, the call to `document.write` will wipe out the entire contents of the document, including the script.

Comment: "Browsers rarely update the page before a function has finished processing" Where did you get that from?

Comment: That's how they work. The browser doesn't know when script has finished modifying a page, so rather than display changes as they happen (which would be annoying), they wait util all changes have been made then show  a single update. `document.write` is a little different, some browsers will display the results immediately but others may wait.

Comment: I don't know Rob, a [simple test](http://jsfiddle.net/bkDwe/) seems to support @valentinas observation. Can you provide a counter-demonstration or something in the specification?

Comment: Have you tried it in an iPad? In IE 8 half the time the second prompt appears before the page is rendered. And on my iPhone, the word "test" doesn't appear until after the second prompt is dismissed.

Comment: Initial impression: *You have an iPad with IE8 on it?* Let me check it out... on Win7. I tested on Chrome.

Comment: I was kidding, I just thought it was funny, initial impressions and all. Something bothered me about the original, so I changed the `test` output to two different statements: http://jsfiddle.net/bkDwe/1/ What I noticed was the example might be flawed due to the way jsFiddle itself is loaded. But I still see all of the popups if I `Run`. Hmm.

Comment: Ok (@valentinas and RobG), here's a test in a jsFiddle-free file and it doesn't show the outputs of the `document.write`'s until after the `alert`s have all fired: http://jfcoder.com/test/popup.html That's in IE 9, by the way, Chrome shows it just as it would run in the code, ie, as you would expect it to run in order.

Comment: @JaredFarrish—thanks for sticking with it. BTW, the last alert should be `After test 2.`

Comment: Cool. The confirm also plays a part, as everything stops when a modal dialogue presented. So if the page hasn't rendered at that point (even though the function has requested it to), it won't until the dialog is dismissed. And if it's immediately redirected, it may not bother updating either (what's the point?). Note also that your tests use trivial pages that should render almost instantly, a more complex page will take longer and will be more likely to be not rendered when the dialogue is displayed.

Comment: chrome and FF will update document instantly, also IE will update document instantly too if you wait for document to render and then run the function. So I still think that "Browsers rarely update the page before a function has finished processing." is misleading. Also document.write() is a function too, so technically... Also, what happens when you have something like this: http://pastebin.com/wBrvPBFN ? I've tried couple of variations and it seems that alert() is blocking things on IE, e.g. if you remove alert before document.write() it will make the modifications to document instantly.